# This project does not use the Gradle build system

Tags: android

Good Day ,

I m new in Android studio , I was importing one application and I m getting this error :

```
  This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
     More Information about migrating to Gradle
     Don't show this message again.
```

If you can help me will be thankful

Regards

Comment: possible duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362473/being-told-project-is-not-using-the-gradle-build-system-when-it-is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606504/cant-migrate-project-to-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: Are you migrating Eclipse project?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094169/migrate-project-to-gradle-error

Comment: I fixed the problem by updating the Gradle . Thanks in advance